# getInitialProps import data in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a simple page in `NEXT.js` for example like this:

```
function Page({ stars }) {
    return <div>Next stars: {stars}</div>;
}

Page.getInitialProps = async ({ req }) => {
    const res = await fetch('https://api.github.com/repos/zeit/next.js');
    //console.log(res) shows data at-it-is, -raw
    const json = await res.json();
    return { stars: json.stargazers_count };
};

export default Page;
```

and a data-set from API `https://directmarketaccess.ru/api/curves/curves/3`
in such format which is needed for Google React Chart in exactly the same view at they are like:

```
[
   [header1,..headerX]
   ...
   [valueY,...valueY]
]
```

It's not an `object` with `{}` it's an `array` of `arrays`

> According to the dataset from Google Charts [Demo line chart](https://github.com/RakanNimer/react-google-charts/blob/HEAD/sandboxes/linechart/index.js) - array of arrays is fine

I spent almost two days for understanding this case and such tutorials like:

- https://nextjs.org/learn/excel/lazy-loading-modules/lazy-loading
- https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/fetching-data-for-pages

and searching for answers from google/SO/etc. Probably I don't understand something or missing a trivial thing, but in some cases after importing data with `getInititalProps` even after `console.log(res)` stage, I receive error every time when I'm trying to import everything that isn't an object with properties. The funny thing is, that after all the experiments `console.log(res)` show data correctly, even if server refure to render page for me. So what if necessary data are a `string`, `number`, `array`, but not an `object` (let skip part where typeof array === object). How to import data in necessary format with or without `getInitialProps`?

Is there any way to import data on page as-they-are (for example from async function in other file, that connecting to DB (mongo) and receiving data from it) or I always should use `fetch` from API which should sent me `object` with `{prop: value}` model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put any type of data as the property of an object, including an array of arrays.

Just fetch the data, and in `getInitialProps`, return it as:

```
function Page({ data }) {
    // render your chart here with `data`
}

Page.getInitialProps = async ({ req }) => {
    const res = await fetch(GOOGLE_CHARTS_API);
    const json = await res.json(); // `json` is your array of arrays of data
    return { data: json };
};

export default Page;
```

Comment: I'll re-test this solution once more in a moment, but last time it trigger an error with print like `React child component...`

Comment: @AlexZeDim Feel free to add more information with the full code that you're using.

Comment: Ahaha, the funny thing is that it works, but I literally missed it a couple of hours ago. And I know why, so could clarify for me a couple of things? First: why when using comment `const json = await res.json();` and just `return { data: res }` it gives me: `Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Response]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead. in div (at another.js:4) in Page in Container in App in Context.Provider in Context.Provider in Context.Provider in Context.Provider`

Comment: Should I convect received data from `fetch` to json everytime?

Comment: @AlexZeDim I'd need to see what's in your `render()` method to help you figure out why you're getting that error, but you can't put JS objects directly as React children - you can only render strings and other JS primitives.

Comment: For your second question, yes, you should always convert the received data using `.json()` every time.

Comment: And the second thing: As i mentioned in question, if I import from another function `array` for example `[1,2,3]` I see in `console.log()` as `[1,2,3]` -raw, but when I render in `on page` it's just `123`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192456/discussion-between-clarence-leung-and-alexzedim).